# Gatsby will not work with Strapi after going back to Development database

Tags: gatsby, strapi, gatsby-plugin

> I am getting this error after switching my settings from my production environment using postgres and then to my dev environment using sqlite. Switching between the two was fine before, but I did update my node version. Not sure if that could have had an effect. I do have public permission, so I don't get what's happening here..

**Steps:**

gatsby develop

> I then get:

info Starting to fetch data from Strapi - http://localhost:1337/announcements?_limit=1000
info Starting to fetch data from Strapi - http://localhost:1337/players?_limit=1000
info Starting to fetch data from Strapi - http://localhost:1337/basics?_limit=1000
info Starting to fetch data from Strapi - http://localhost:1337/results?_limit=1000
info Starting to fetch data from Strapi - http://localhost:1337/about?_limit=1000
info Starting to fetch data from Strapi - http://localhost:1337/calendar?_limit=1000
success Fetched Strapi Data - 0.128s

ERROR #11321 PLUGIN

"gatsby-source-strapi" threw an error while running the sourceNodes lifecycle:

Request failed with status code 500

**System**

Node.js version: 12.14.1
NPM version: 6.14.8
Strapi version: 3.1.0-alpha.1
Database: sqlite3
Operating system: Catalina 10.15.7

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my problem. It had to do with the build and project versions not being the same. This also affected my cloudinary plugin, which I then removed and reinstalled. Basically follow these steps: https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/guides/update-version.html#upgrading-your-dependencies.